# How to get open app from file manager and get path of that file?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to open my app from file manager by clicking a file(this is almost done) and play that file. But how can I **get the path of that particular video file** so that I can open it?

after using below code(showing red error but working) inside activity inside manifest, my app is shown as an option for opening that file:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

image:
[image]

How to **get path of the file** that I clicked in file manager before showing above picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I get the path of that particular video file so that I can open it?

Frequently, you don't.

You call `getIntent()` on the `Activity` that has that `<intent-filter>`, and on there you call `getData()` to get a `Uri` to the content that the user wishes to view.

Occasionally, given that `<intent-filter>`, you will get a `Uri` whose scheme is `file`. In that case, calling `getPath()` on the `Uri` will return a filesystem path. It is unlikely that you can *use* that path, particularly on Android 10 and higher, because whatever app started yours has a bug — `file` `Uri` values have been generally banned since Android 7.0.

More often, you will get a `Uri` with another scheme. In these cases, the `Uri` does not necessarily represent a file on the filesystem that you can access. Instead, you do something based on the scheme to get access to the content:

- For a scheme of `content` or `android.resource` (or `file`), use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content
- For a scheme of `http` or `https`, use your favorite HTTP client API (e.g., OkHttp) to download the content
- And so on, for whatever schemes you wish to support

If you want to limit your activity to only support a subset of schemes, use `<data>` elements in the `<intent-filter>` to list the scheme(s) that you do support.

In your case, if you are looking to play back videos, you may be able to just pass the `Uri` to whatever you are using for video playback (e.g., ExoPlayer) and let *it* deal with all the headaches of actually loading the content.

Comment: thanks. I can simply pass the uri(`getIntent().getData()`) to exoplayer.